# Passing many attributes quasar select

Tags: vuejs2, quasar-framework

I receive these data on created cycle of component:

```
{title: ‘any title’, type: ‘medical’, id: ‘mongo objectid here’}
```

and I make my q-select passing title and id to it. But, how could I get a third attribute/parameter on change event of my select to get the type value?
Example: I would like to get, on change event of my select, the value of the selected option and in somewhere get also the type. In others words, something like that:

```
<select>
   <option value="any value" type="medical">Any title </option>
   <option value="any value 2" type="child">Another title here </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your `value` an object containing the type and id. Like this:

```
data () {
    selectOptions: [{
        label: yourInitialObject.title,
        value: {
           id: yourInitialObject.id,
           type: yourInitialObject.type
        }
    }]
}
```

And then use it with `q-select` like this:

```
<q-select :options="selectOptions" v-model="selectedOption" @input="onSelectionChanged"/>
```

The `@input` event passes the new value to a method of your choosing where you can access the type, or you just use the bound v-model:

```
onSelectionChanged: function (newValue) {
    console.log(newValue.id)
    console.log(newValue.type)
}
```

This may not be the cleanest solution, but it get's the job done. Alternatively you could just define the `value` to be the id (since it is unique) and then if you need the `type` do a search inside your original array. The options array could be created by a computed property then for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You saved my project, however, I used the alternative you said about how to find a value inside my array.